# Linq c# group/sum a lot of columns

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I Have a List object (object with more than 250 attribute) , I want to do a group by two columns (string) and then sum all the rest (double) , 
is there any solution to avoid making the sum one by one and do it for all double attributes ,

This list I'm getting it from XML file and not from a database query

```
var xx = Data.MyList.GroupBy(grp => new MyObject()
            {
                Name = grp.Name,
                Date = grp.Date,

            }).Select(slt => new MyObject()
            {
                Name = slt.Key.Name,
                Date = slt.Key.Date,

                eq = slt.Sum(x=>x.eq),
                eq1 = slt.Sum(x=>x.eq1),
                eq2 = slt.Sum(x=>x.eq2),
                eq3 = slt.Sum(x=>x.eq3),
                .
                .
                .
                eq250 = slt.Sum(x=>x.eq2505),
                }).ToList();
```

Thanks to HimBromBeere here is the Solution

```
 var grpBySub = Data.MyList.GroupBy(grp => new
        {
             grp.Name,
             grp.Date,
        }).Select(slt => new 
        {
            slt.Key.Name,
            slt.Key.Date,
            Sums = typeof(MyObject).GetProperties().Where(y =>
                y.Name != "Name" &&
                y.Name != "Date" &&

                ).Select(p => new
            {
                p.Name,
                Sum = slt.Sum(entity => ((double?)p.GetValue(entity, null))) 

            }).ToList()

        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Post some code and show what your have tried.

Comment: One database-entity with 250 attributes? Sounds quite weird, maybe you should consider to normalize your datastructure?

Comment: Do you mean to have a single gouping depending on two columns or two separete groupings based on one column each?

Comment: You may use reflection to gett all those attributes that do NOT match your desired ones. Howevber this leads to reflection-horror.

Comment: Use a `List<double>` instead and normalize your database by creating a related table where each attribute is one linked record.

Comment: it's not from a data base , but from XML file with 150 column

Comment: if the xml is that large, it might be better importing it to a dataset then working against that. The trouble with trying to work with xml is that everything is string based, so this complicates the math.

Comment: @bilpor String-based? Only if you parse XML by hand. You´ve heard from serilalization? You´ll get strongly typed attributes there.

Comment: i've already got the xml and put it into a list of object , the problem is in the object with many attributes

Comment: Write some short similar datastructure that contains the two grouping-attributes and at least two attributes from the rest.

Comment: if You have placed these into a list of objects then the attributes should have become properties

Comment: exactly , now how to do a group by , and the sum of the double properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, although its probably bad design for one entity to have so many attributes you may use reflection to get the attributes values and sum them:

```
var properties = typeof(MyEntity).GetProperties().ToList();
myEntities.GroupBy(x => x.numerator)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Key = g.Key,
            Sums = properties.Select(p => new 
            { 
                Name = p.Name, 
                Sum = g.Sum(entity => (int)p.GetValue(entity, null)) 
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: @user3708197 Edited my answer completely. Now it should work

Comment: can I get us output the same list type us the input list

Comment: What do you mean with same type as input-list? Your input isn´t gropued at all, so your result should be nested in any way. Furthermore if you mean you need a list of `MyEntity` that´ll work. however you have to manually assign every property of `MyEntity` to its related value within the anonymous type, e.g. `new MyEntity { SumAttr3 = ..., SumAttr4 = ... }`

Comment: thank you , yes I ment that my output list should be MyEntity  , I think your solution do the job , i'm getting an esception : InvalidCstException I think because there are some null values which we Shouldn't do the sum

Comment: @user3708197 You should also exclude the properties you used for the group by writing a matching `Where`-Statement after the `GetProperties`-call.

Comment: it works My friend , thank you very much , I think the only solution to get a list of MyEntity is to manually assign every property of MyEntity to its related value that's sad :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing it over an XML document, you don't necessarily need to resort to reflection. A very rough and unpolished example:

```
var xml = @"<root>
               <element groupAttr1=""1"" groupAttr2=""2"" someAttr1=""1"" someAttr2=""2"" />
               <element groupAttr1=""1"" groupAttr2=""2"" someAttr1=""3"" someAttr2=""4"" />
            </root>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var groupped = xDoc.Root
                   .Elements("element")
                   .GroupBy(el => new
                                  {
                                     GroupAttr1 = el.Attribute("groupAttr1")?.Value,
                                     GroupAttr2 = el.Attribute("groupAttr2")?.Value
                                  })
                   .Select(x => new
                                {
                                   Key = x.Key,
                                   Sums = x.Select(
                                      el => el.Attributes()
                                              .Where(a => a.Name != "groupAttr1"
                                                       && a.Name != "groupAttr2")
                                              .Sum(a => double.Parse(a.Value)))
                                });
```